# OCaml expected type 'a

Tags: ocaml

I am attempting to make a function such that it outputs a list that removes adjacent duplicates

```
let rec rem_adj_duplicates l = 
    let rec utn l n = match l with
        [] -> n
        | (x :: y :: xs) -> if (x != y) then utn (y::xs) (n::x)
            else utn (y::xs) n
    in utn l []
```

I get the following error:

> Error: This expression has type 'a list
>          but an expression was expected of type 'a
>          The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list

Why does n want to be type 'a instead of 'a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
if (x != y) then
    utn (y::xs) (n::x)
else
    utn (y::xs) n
```

In the first call you have `n :: x`, which says that x is a list and n is a non-list. Furthermore it says that the second argument to `utn` is a list. In the next call you have just `n`, which must be of the same type as the other call. Thus, n shows up as both a list and a non-list.

Possibly you wanted to have `x :: n` rather than `n :: x`?

**Update**

You say you're not allowed to use the `@` operator. This is actually reasonable, as using it in the way you wanted is not a good way to solve the problem. (Adding things one at a time to the end of a list is slow, i.e., quadratic time in the length of the list.)

I may be giving away too much, but a common way to solve this problem is to build the list in reverse order and reverse it at the end. This takes only linear time.

Comment: what I want is for x to be added onto the end of list n.

Comment: This is a very slow operation, so not something you'd really want to do in production code :-) But the expression for this is `n @ [x]`.

Comment: ok, that works, but I am actually restricted to not using the @ operator :/